# RX for .NET - When calling observer.OnCompleted from within Disposable.Create nothing happens

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I'm playing around with the RX libraries for .NET in C#. Can anyone explain to me why the 'observer.OnCompleted()' method does nothing in the following code:

```
var observableStream = Observable.Create<CustomMessage>(
       (observer) =>
           {
               CustomMessage cm = new CustomMessage();
               CustomMessage.Subscribe(observer.OnNext);

               return Disposable.Create(
               () =>
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Disposing...");
                       CustomMessage.Unsubscribe(observer.OnNext);                          
                       observer.OnCompleted();                //***Nothing happens here***
                   }
               );
       });

    //IObserver.OnException()
    public override void OnException(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred - " + e.Message);
    }

    //IObserver.OnComplete()
    public override void OnUnsubscribe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribed...");            
    }

    //IObserver.OnNext()
    public override void HandleNextMsg(IRVMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance received a message");
    }

IDisposable myDisposable = observableStream.Subscribe(HandleNextMsg, OnException, OnUnsubscribe);

//At some later point....
myDisposable.Dispose();
```

The code is intended to make a subscription to a stream of CustomMessages. It registers the observer.OnNext() method with my CustomMessage type when setting up a subscription. It then de-registers the observer.OnNext() when disposing of the subscription. All of this works correctly. My 'HandleNextMsg()' method is called whenever a CustomMessage is received.

At some later point when I wish to terminate my subscription I call 'Dispose()' and the following two lines are successfully executed:

```
Console.WriteLine("Disposing...");
CustomMessage.Unsubscribe(observer.OnNext);
```

I then receive no more CustomMessages. However the following line, although executed, does nothing:

```
observer.OnCompleted();
```

I expected it to call the line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Unsubscribed...");
```

At some point the connection between the observer and the 'OnUnsubscribe' method is lost and I'd like to understand exactly what's going on. How is it that the 'observer.OnNext()' can be successfully de-registered, but 'observer.OnCompleted()' does nothing?

It's been pointed out to me that just because I'm disposing the stream doesn't mean I should be calling 'OnCompleted()' but I'd still like to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is caused by the way `Observable.Create` wraps the function you passed and any observers you subscribe to the resulting `IObservable`.  Basically, the flow is:

- Observable.Create returns an AnonymousObservable.
- AnonymousObservable wraps observers in an AutoDetachObserver in Subscribe.
- AnonymousObservable returns the AutoDetachObserver (which implements IDisposable) from Subscribe.
- AutoDetachObserver.Dispose sets its stopped flag and **then** disposes the object your original subscribe function returned.  This flag causes the observer to ignore future calls to OnError and OnCompleted, thus causing the wrapped observer methods to not be called.

This answer is based on v1.x of RX, but I expect this did not change in v2.0.

If you have some code that needs to run no matter how the subscription ends (OnError, OnCompleted, or Dispose), I would suggest [Observable.Finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212133%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Works with Rx Java too!

Answer (score 5):

OnCompleted() is meant to notify the subscribers that the upstream sequence (CustomMessage in your case) has ended. It's not meant to be a confirmation that the subscriber requested unsubscribe has succeeded, which seems to be how you're trying to use it. OnCompleted() is a notification about the sequence, for ALL subscribers, not for one individual subscription to that sequence.

In other words, you shouldn't want to call it in your Dispose. After all, the subscriber is doing the unsubscribing itself, why would it need to be notified?

As for the actual technical reason why nothing happens, I'm guessing the callbacks (by design) don't carry through when you're already disposing. Just a theory, it's not very relevant.

Comment: A good explanation thanks. As I mentioned, I guessed afterwards that it was incorrect to call OnCompleted but you've given a good explanation as to why this is the case thanks.